# Licensing on forked projects

Tags: open-source, licensing, forking

I forked a project that hasn't been maintained for a while now. I have a lot of changes I'd like to implement and want to actively maintain the project and keep it open source.

How does the licensing work for situations like this? The original project is licensed under [MIT](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php) and I would like to keep it that way. Would I be able to change the licence's copyright holders or would it have to stay the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's great that you want to keep the license the same: that makes things easier. As far as copyright holders are concerned: you can add to the list of copyright holders, but do not remove any names from the list.

This changes (I believe) if at some point in the future you have removed all contributions from one of the holders: at that point you could remove that particular name from the list.